# Why is Power BI Rounding up my values?

Tags: formatting, powerbi, powerquery

Why is Power BI doing this to my values? (see video below) It is setting them to 1.00 in the visualization even though they are 99.61, 99.74, etc. in the query table. What is happening? I have tried setting the type to percentage, decimal, and fixed decimal and the same thing always happens. Also the values are set to "don't summarize" in the visualization table.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNHzelJTW7g&feature=youtu.be

See video to understand what I'm talking about.

Here are a couple screenshots from the video:

[image: Screenshot #1]
[image]

Comment: Please post a code example, the expected results and the actual results instead of linking a video. If the video is deleted, this question becomes useless for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query editor you have the following values:

```
99.79%, 99.91%, 99.74%, 99.82%, 99.74%, 99.61%
```

These are in percent format as is clear by the "%" symbol next to your column name.

When you close and load, you put in in a table which is not formatted as a percent and shows only two decimal places. When rounded to two decimal places the value rounds up to 1.00 for all of these. (Note that your total rounds to 5.99 though.)

If you want them formatted as percentages, use the modeling tab to set the format for the column. (The format you set in the query editor doesn't necessarily carry through to your visualizations.)

[image: Modeling Tab]

Comment: Okay thank you, this works. However, I still do not understand why why the format I set in the query editor would not carry over to visualizations. This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @DerekFisher The `formatting` you did in query editor is `data manipulation`, it changes the underlying data; the `formatting` in the visual UI is `data visualization`, it changes how the data is displayed. That's why the "formatting" won't carry over as they're not for the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your visual, then, in Format visual, go to call-out value and change display units to none and change Value decimal places to the amount of decimals you need.